# How to make MessageDlg centered on owner form

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

I'd like that MessageDlg appear centered on its parent form.
Any suggestions on how to accomplish this in Delphi 2010?

I found the code below here: http://delphi.about.com/od/formsdialogs/l/aa010304a.htm but it's not working for me. The pop-up still is not centered on the owner form. (It's not clear to me how the method would actually *know* the owner form...)

```
 function TForm1.MessageDlg(const Msg: string; DlgType: TMsgDlgType;
   Buttons: TMsgDlgButtons; HelpCtx: Integer): Integer;
 begin
   with CreateMessageDialog(Msg, DlgType, Buttons) do
     try
       Position := poOwnerFormCenter;
       Result := ShowModal
     finally
       Free
     end
 end;
```

Comment: The more I use this solution, the happier I am!  With many applications these days being multi-monitor apps, unless you do something like this, your user may frequently have to look to a different monitor to see a pop-up message.  This is especially true of applications that have non-modal forms that users can position on other monitors...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do

```
function MessageDlg(const AOwner: TForm; const Msg: string; DlgType: TMsgDlgType;
  Buttons: TMsgDlgButtons; HelpCtx: Integer = 0): Integer;
begin
  with CreateMessageDialog(Msg, DlgType, Buttons) do
    try
      Left := AOwner.Left + (AOwner.Width - Width) div 2;
      Top := AOwner.Top + (AOwner.Height - Height) div 2;
      Result := ShowModal;
    finally
      Free;
    end
end;
```

and call it like

```
procedure TForm1.FormClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  MessageDlg(Self, 'This is a test', mtInformation, [mbOK]);
end;
```

However, I would personally not do this, because the dialog shown by `CreateMessageDialog` is not a native Windows dialog. Compare the visual result with the native stuff:

```
procedure TForm1.FormClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  case MessageBox(Handle, PChar('This is a test. Do you wish to do something?'), PChar('A Silly Example'), MB_ICONQUESTION or MB_YESNO) of
    ID_YES:
      MessageBox(Handle, PChar('Great!'), PChar('A Silly Example'), MB_ICONINFORMATION or MB_OK);
    ID_NO:
      MessageBox(Handle, PChar('OK, well, I cannot force you...'), PChar('A Silly Example'), MB_ICONINFORMATION or MB_OK);
  end;
end;
```

At least in Windows 7 with the Aero theme enabled, the native dialog looks *much* better. However, it seems, this cannot be centered over any particular form. Instead, the dialog is centered on the current monitor. But this is also the default behaviour in Windows (try Notepad, WordPad, or Paint), so why do you need this new behaviour?

Comment: Hi, Andreas: Thanks for your answer. I need it because I have a small pop-up form that users slide up into a corner of the screen so it doesn't cover the main form (it's non-modal).  While they're working on in it, if I want to pop-up a message, it looks wrong (IMO) to have the message box "way over" in the middle of the screen rather than centered on the form...

Answer (score 14):

The dialog doesn't have a relationship with the instance of TForm1. It would not be hard to set the position of the form manually, but I bet someone who is more familiar with this area of the VCL will know how to do it a cleaner way.

Personally I never use the Position property and use my own code to position all my forms because I've never been satisfied with the performance of the Position property.

UPDATE: You can change the owner of the dialog using `Self.InsertComponent(Dialog)`. You'd have to store your dialog into a local variable, say, `Dialog`, for this to work:

```
function TForm1.MessageDlg(const Msg: string; DlgType: TMsgDlgType;
  Buttons: TMsgDlgButtons; HelpCtx: Integer): Integer;
var
  Dialog: TForm;
begin
  Dialog := CreateMessageDialog(Msg, DlgType, Buttons);
  try
    Self.InsertComponent(Dialog);
    Dialog.Position := poOwnerFormCenter;
    Result := Dialog.ShowModal
  finally
    Dialog.Free
  end
end;
```

Comment: CreateMessageDialog creates the form and sets the Owner to "Application". As the Owner property is readonly and the FOwner field (TComponent) is private, there is no clean way to "re-owner" a form once it is instantiated. So, using CreateMessageDialog there is no way to create the needed relationship. You would have to re-implement (make your own version of) CreateMessageDialog with an extra parameter to create the needed relationship when the message form is instantiated.

Comment: @Marjan Yes you can re-owner a form, just as I have described above. In fact I've just edited it because it can be done even simpler, without recourse to RemoveComponent, as in an earlier version of my answer.

Comment: As usual, David, great answer. I've already folded this into my code.  I and my users thank you! :-) (Also voted up your answer... or does that contribute to "point inflation?!"

Comment: Never thought of that one! :D

Comment: @David Heffernan I was looking for a solution to this centering issue. Your suggestion worked perfectly, almost. It works the first time it is called. The following calls generate access violations. Stepping through the code line by line it seems its the CreateMessageDialog line that causes the access violation. I use Delphi 6.

Comment: Delphi6 `InsertComponent` does not call `RemoveComponent` internally, but D2007 does.

Answer (score 8):

Why limit this desire to message dialogs? Like David Heffernan [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4618743/how-to-make-messagedlg-centered-on-owner-form#comment5079250_4618877):

> Native dialogs always win!

With the following unit(s), you can center *any* native dialog, such as: `MessageBox`, `TFindDialog`, `TOpenDialog`, `TFontDialog`, `TPrinterSetupDialog`, etc... The main unit provides two routines, both with some optional parameters:

```
function ExecuteCentered(Dialog: TCommonDialog;
  WindowToCenterIn: HWND = 0): Boolean;
function MsgBox(const Text: String; Flags: Cardinal = DefFlags;
  const Caption: String = DefCaption;
  WindowToCenterIn: HWND = 0): Integer;
```

Wherelse you would use `OpenDialog1.Execute` and let Windows decide where to show the dialog, you now use `ExecuteCentered(OpenDialog1)` and the dialog is centered in the screen's active form:

[image: Centered find dialog]

To show message dialogs, use `MsgBox`, a wrapper around `Application.MessageBox` (which in turn is a wrapper around `Windows.MessageBox`). Some examples:

- `MsgBox('Hello world!');`
- `MsgBox('Cancel saving?', MB_YESNO or MB_ICONQUESTION or MB_DEFBUTTON2);`
- `MsgBox('Please try again.', MB_OK, 'Error');`
- `MsgBox('I''m centered in the toolbar.', MB_OK, 'Fun!', Toolbar1.Handle);`

The units:

```
unit AwDialogs;

interface

uses
  Dialogs, Forms, Windows, Controls, Messages, AwHookInstance, Math, MultiMon;

const
  DefCaption = 'Application.Title';
  DefFlags = MB_OK;

procedure CenterWindow(WindowToStay, WindowToCenter: HWND);
function GetTopWindow: HWND;

function ExecuteCentered(Dialog: TCommonDialog;
  WindowToCenterIn: HWND = 0): Boolean;
function MsgBox(const Text: String; Flags: Cardinal = DefFlags;
  const Caption: String = DefCaption;
  WindowToCenterIn: HWND = 0): Integer;

implementation

procedure CenterWindow(WindowToStay, WindowToCenter: HWND);
var
  R1: TRect;
  R2: TRect;
  Monitor: HMonitor;
  MonInfo: TMonitorInfo;
  MonRect: TRect;
  X: Integer;
  Y: Integer;
begin
  GetWindowRect(WindowToStay, R1);
  GetWindowRect(WindowToCenter, R2);
  Monitor := MonitorFromWindow(WindowToStay, MONITOR_DEFAULTTONEAREST);
  MonInfo.cbSize := SizeOf(MonInfo);
  GetMonitorInfo(Monitor, @MonInfo);
  MonRect := MonInfo.rcWork;
  with R1 do
  begin
    X := (Right - Left - R2.Right + R2.Left) div 2 + Left;
    Y := (Bottom - Top - R2.Bottom + R2.Top) div 2 + Top;
  end;
  X := Max(MonRect.Left, Min(X, MonRect.Right - R2.Right + R2.Left));
  Y := Max(MonRect.Top, Min(Y, MonRect.Bottom - R2.Bottom + R2.Top));
  SetWindowPos(WindowToCenter, 0, X, Y, 0, 0, SWP_NOACTIVATE or
    SWP_NOOWNERZORDER or SWP_NOSIZE or SWP_NOZORDER);
end;

function GetTopWindow: HWND;
begin
  Result := GetLastActivePopup(Application.Handle);
  if (Result = Application.Handle) or not IsWindowVisible(Result) then
    Result := Screen.ActiveCustomForm.Handle;
end;

{ TAwCommonDialog }

type
  TAwCommonDialog = class(TObject)
  private
    FCenterWnd: HWND;
    FDialog: TCommonDialog;
    FHookProc: TFarProc;
    FWndHook: HHOOK;
    procedure HookProc(var Message: THookMessage);
    function Execute: Boolean;
  end;

function TAwCommonDialog.Execute: Boolean;
begin
  try
    Application.NormalizeAllTopMosts;
    FHookProc := MakeHookInstance(HookProc);
    FWndHook := SetWindowsHookEx(WH_CALLWNDPROCRET, FHookProc, 0,
      GetCurrentThreadID);
    Result := FDialog.Execute;
  finally
    if FWndHook <> 0 then
      UnhookWindowsHookEx(FWndHook);
    if FHookProc <> nil then
      FreeHookInstance(FHookProc);
    Application.RestoreTopMosts;
  end;
end;

procedure TAwCommonDialog.HookProc(var Message: THookMessage);
var
  Data: PCWPRetStruct;
  Parent: HWND;
begin
  with Message do
    if nCode < 0 then
      Result := CallNextHookEx(FWndHook, nCode, wParam, lParam)
    else
      Result := 0;
  if Message.nCode = HC_ACTION then
  begin
    Data := PCWPRetStruct(Message.lParam);
    if (FDialog.Handle <> 0) and (Data.message = WM_SHOWWINDOW) then
    begin
      Parent := GetWindowLong(FDialog.Handle, GWL_HWNDPARENT);
      if ((Data.hwnd = FDialog.Handle) and (Parent = Application.Handle)) or
        ((Data.hwnd = FDialog.Handle) and (FDialog is TFindDialog)) or
        (Data.hwnd = Parent) then
      begin
        CenterWindow(FCenterWnd, Data.hwnd);
        SetWindowPos(Data.hwnd, HWND_TOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOMOVE or
          SWP_NOSIZE or SWP_NOACTIVATE or SWP_NOOWNERZORDER);
        UnhookWindowsHookEx(FWndHook);
        FWndHook := 0;
        FreeHookInstance(FHookProc);
        FHookProc := nil;
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;

function ExecuteCentered(Dialog: TCommonDialog;
  WindowToCenterIn: HWND = 0): Boolean;
begin
  with TAwCommonDialog.Create do
  try
    if WindowToCenterIn = 0 then
      FCenterWnd := GetTopWindow
    else
      FCenterWnd := WindowToCenterIn;
    FDialog := Dialog;
    Result := Execute;
  finally
    Free;
  end;
end;

{ TAwMessageBox }

type
  TAwMessageBox = class(TObject)
  private
    FCaption: String;
    FCenterWnd: HWND;
    FFlags: Cardinal;
    FHookProc: TFarProc;
    FText: String;
    FWndHook: HHOOK;
    function Execute: Integer;
    procedure HookProc(var Message: THookMessage);
  end;

function TAwMessageBox.Execute: Integer;
begin
  try
    try
      Application.NormalizeAllTopMosts;
      FHookProc := MakeHookInstance(HookProc);
      FWndHook := SetWindowsHookEx(WH_CALLWNDPROCRET, FHookProc, 0,
        GetCurrentThreadID);
      Result := Application.MessageBox(PChar(FText), PChar(FCaption), FFlags);
    finally
      if FWndHook <> 0 then
        UnhookWindowsHookEx(FWndHook);
      if FHookProc <> nil then
        FreeHookInstance(FHookProc);
      Application.RestoreTopMosts;
    end;
  except
    Result := 0;
  end;
end;

procedure TAwMessageBox.HookProc(var Message: THookMessage);
var
  Data: PCWPRetStruct;
  Title: array[0..255] of Char;
begin
  with Message do
    if nCode < 0 then
      Result := CallNextHookEx(FWndHook, nCode, wParam, lParam)
    else
      Result := 0;
  if Message.nCode = HC_ACTION then
  begin
    Data := PCWPRetStruct(Message.lParam);
    if Data.message = WM_INITDIALOG then
    begin
      FillChar(Title, SizeOf(Title), 0);
      GetWindowText(Data.hwnd, @Title, SizeOf(Title));
      if String(Title) = FCaption then
      begin
        CenterWindow(FCenterWnd, Data.hwnd);
        SetWindowPos(Data.hwnd, HWND_TOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOMOVE or
          SWP_NOSIZE or SWP_NOACTIVATE or SWP_NOOWNERZORDER);
        UnhookWindowsHookEx(FWndHook);
        FWndHook := 0;
        FreeHookInstance(FHookProc);
        FHookProc := nil;
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;

function MsgBox(const Text: String; Flags: Cardinal = DefFlags;
  const Caption: String = DefCaption;
  WindowToCenterIn: HWND = 0): Integer;
begin
  with TAwMessageBox.Create do
  try
    if Caption = DefCaption then
      FCaption := Application.Title
    else
      FCaption := Caption;
    if WindowToCenterIn = 0 then
      FCenterWnd := GetTopWindow
    else
      FCenterWnd := WindowToCenterIn;
    FFlags := Flags;
    FText := Text;
    Result := Execute;
  finally
    Free;
  end;
end;

end.
```

```
unit AwHookInstance;

interface

uses
  Windows;

type
  THookMessage = packed record
    nCode: Integer;
    wParam: WPARAM;
    lParam: LPARAM;
    Result: LRESULT;
  end;

  THookMethod = procedure(var Message: THookMessage) of object;

function MakeHookInstance(Method: THookMethod): Pointer;
procedure FreeHookInstance(HookInstance: Pointer);

implementation

const
  InstanceCount = 313;

type
  PHookInstance = ^THookInstance;
  THookInstance = packed record
    Code: Byte;
    Offset: Integer;
    case Integer of
      0: (Next: PHookInstance);
      1: (Method: THookMethod);
  end;

  PInstanceBlock = ^TInstanceBlock;
  TInstanceBlock = packed record
    Next: PInstanceBlock;
    Code: array[1..2] of Byte;
    HookProcPtr: Pointer;
    Instances: array[0..InstanceCount] of THookInstance;
  end;

var
  InstBlockList: PInstanceBlock;
  InstFreeList: PHookInstance;

function StdHookProc(nCode: Integer; wParam: WPARAM;
  lParam: LPARAM): LRESULT; stdcall; assembler;
{ In    ECX = Address of method pointer }
{ Out   EAX = Result }
asm
  XOR     EAX,EAX
  PUSH    EAX
  PUSH    LParam
  PUSH    WParam
  PUSH    nCode
  MOV     EDX,ESP
  MOV     EAX,[ECX].Longint[4]
  CALL    [ECX].Pointer
  ADD     ESP,12
  POP     EAX
end;

function CalcJmpOffset(Src, Dest: Pointer): Longint;
begin
  Result := Longint(Dest) - (Longint(Src) + 5);
end;

function MakeHookInstance(Method: THookMethod): Pointer;
const
  BlockCode: array[1..2] of Byte = ($59 { POP ECX }, $E9 { JMP StdHookProc });
  PageSize = 4096;
var
  Block: PInstanceBlock;
  Instance: PHookInstance;
begin
  if InstFreeList = nil then
  begin
    Block := VirtualAlloc(nil, PageSize, MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);
    Block^.Next := InstBlockList;
    Move(BlockCode, Block^.Code, SizeOf(BlockCode));
    Block^.HookProcPtr := Pointer(CalcJmpOffset(@Block^.Code[2], @StdHookProc));
    Instance := @Block^.Instances;
    repeat
      Instance^.Code := $E8;  { CALL NEAR PTR Offset }
      Instance^.Offset := CalcJmpOffset(Instance, @Block^.Code);
      Instance^.Next := InstFreeList;
      InstFreeList := Instance;
      Inc(Longint(Instance), SizeOf(THookInstance));
    until Longint(Instance) - Longint(Block) >= SizeOf(TInstanceBlock);
    InstBlockList := Block;
  end;
  Result := InstFreeList;
  Instance := InstFreeList;
  InstFreeList := Instance^.Next;
  Instance^.Method := Method;
end;

procedure FreeHookInstance(HookInstance: Pointer);
begin
  if HookInstance <> nil then
  begin
    PHookInstance(HookInstance)^.Next := InstFreeList;
    InstFreeList := HookInstance;
  end;
end;

end.
```

Legal notice: These units are written by me in [this Dutch topic](http://www.nldelphi.com/forum/showthread.php?p=287620#post287620). The original versions are from [Mark van Renswoude](http://www.nldelphi.com/forum/member.php?u=201), see [NLDMessageBox](https://github.com/NLDelphi/NLDMessageBox).

Comment: This works great in 32 bit, fails in 64 bit. Push and POP are giving "[dcc64 Error] HookInstance.pas(57): E2116 Invalid combination of opcode and operands" Any thoughts?

Answer (score 4):

Here's the code I currently use to show a centered dialog over the active form:

```
function MessageDlgCenter(const Msg: string; DlgType: TMsgDlgType;
  Buttons: TMsgDlgButtons): Integer;
var R: TRect;
begin
  if not Assigned(Screen.ActiveForm) then
  begin
    Result := MessageDlg(Msg, DlgType, Buttons, 0);
  end else
  begin
    with CreateMessageDialog(Msg, DlgType, Buttons) do
    try
      GetWindowRect(Screen.ActiveForm.Handle, R);
      Left := R.Left + ((R.Right - R.Left) div 2) - (Width div 2);
      Top := R.Top + ((R.Bottom - R.Top) div 2) - (Height div 2);
      Result := ShowModal;
    finally
      Free;
    end;
  end;
end;
```