# How do I create an alpha blended panel?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

I'm trying to display a truly alpha blended TPanel in Delphi XE2. I've found quite a few attempts online, but none of them work correctly.

What I'm trying to achieve is a 'semi modal' form. A form that is displayed over the top of other controls with a faded background in a similar manner to that seen in web browsers.

[image]

I've got it working in a basic form, but it suffers from the following problems:

- A large amount of flicker when resizing the panel.
- If a control is moved over the top of the panel it leaves a trail.

Here's my efforts thus far (based on some code I found [here](http://delphi-kb.blogspot.no/2011/06/how-to-create-transparent-tpanel_1516.html)).

```
unit SemiModalFormU;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms, Dialogs, ExtCtrls;

type
  ISemiModalResultHandler = interface
    ['{0CC5A5D0-1545-4257-A936-AD777E0DAFCF}']
    procedure SemiModalFormClosed(Form: TForm);
  end;

  TTransparentPanel = class(TCustomPanel)
  private
    FBackground: TBitmap;
    FBlendColor: TColor;
    FBlendAlpha: Byte;

    procedure ColorBlend(const ACanvas: TCanvas; const ARect: TRect; const ABlendColor: TColor; const ABlendValue: Byte);
    procedure SetBlendAlpha(const Value: Byte);
    procedure SetBlendColor(const Value: TColor);
  protected
    procedure CaptureBackground;
    procedure Paint; override;

    procedure WMEraseBkGnd(var msg: TWMEraseBkGnd); message WM_ERASEBKGND;
    procedure WMMove(var Message: TMessage); message WM_MOVE;
    procedure WMParentNotify(var Message: TWMParentNotify); message WM_PARENTNOTIFY;
  public
    constructor Create(aOwner: TComponent); override;
    destructor Destroy; override;

    procedure ClearBackground;

    procedure SetBounds(ALeft, ATop, AWidth, AHeight: Integer); override;
  published
    property BlendColor: TColor read FBlendColor write SetBlendColor;
    property BlendAlpha: Byte read FBlendAlpha write SetBlendAlpha;

    property Align;
    property Alignment;
    property Anchors;
  end;

  TSemiModalForm = class(TComponent)
  strict private
    FFormParent: TWinControl;
    FBlendColor: TColor;
    FBlendAlpha: Byte;
    FSemiModalResultHandler: ISemiModalResultHandler;
    FForm: TForm;
    FTransparentPanel: TTransparentPanel;
    FOldFormOnClose: TCloseEvent;
  private
    procedure OnTransparentPanelResize(Sender: TObject);
    procedure RepositionForm;
    procedure SetFormParent(const Value: TWinControl);
    procedure OnFormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
  protected
    procedure Notification(AComponent: TComponent; Operation: TOperation); override;
  public
    procedure ShowSemiModalForm(AForm: TForm; SemiModalResultHandler: ISemiModalResultHandler); virtual;

    property ModalPanel: TTransparentPanel read FTransparentPanel;
  published
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;

    property BlendColor: TColor read FBlendColor write FBlendColor;
    property BlendAlpha: Byte read FBlendAlpha write FBlendAlpha;
    property FormParent: TWinControl read FFormParent write SetFormParent;
  end;

implementation

procedure TTransparentPanel.CaptureBackground;
var
  canvas: TCanvas;
  dc: HDC;
  sourcerect: TRect;
begin
  FBackground := TBitmap.Create;

  with Fbackground do
  begin
    width := clientwidth;
    height := clientheight;
  end;

  sourcerect.TopLeft := ClientToScreen(clientrect.TopLeft);
  sourcerect.BottomRight := ClientToScreen(clientrect.BottomRight);

  dc := CreateDC('DISPLAY', nil, nil, nil);
  try
    canvas := TCanvas.Create;
    try
      canvas.handle := dc;
      Fbackground.Canvas.CopyRect(clientrect, canvas, sourcerect);
    finally
      canvas.handle := 0;
      canvas.free;
    end;
  finally
    DeleteDC(dc);
  end;
end;

constructor TTransparentPanel.Create(aOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited;

  ControlStyle := controlStyle - [csSetCaption];

  FBlendColor := clWhite;
  FBlendAlpha := 200;
end;

destructor TTransparentPanel.Destroy;
begin
  FreeAndNil(FBackground);

  inherited;
end;

procedure TTransparentPanel.Paint;
begin
  if csDesigning in ComponentState then
    inherited
end;

procedure TTransparentPanel.SetBounds(ALeft, ATop, AWidth, AHeight: Integer);
begin
  if (Visible) and
     (HandleAllocated) and
     (not (csDesigning in ComponentState)) then
  begin
    FreeAndNil(Fbackground);

    Hide;

    inherited;

    Parent.Update;

    Show;
  end
  else
    inherited;
end;

procedure TTransparentPanel.WMEraseBkGnd(var msg: TWMEraseBkGnd);
var
  ACanvas: TCanvas;
begin
  if csDesigning in ComponentState then
    inherited
  else
  begin
    if not Assigned(FBackground) then
      Capturebackground;

    ACanvas := TCanvas.create;
    try
      ACanvas.handle := msg.DC;
      ACanvas.draw(0, 0, FBackground);
      ColorBlend(ACanvas, Rect(0, 0, Width, Height), FBlendColor, FBlendAlpha);
    finally
      FreeAndNil(ACanvas);
    end;

    msg.result := 1;
  end;
end;

procedure TTransparentPanel.WMMove(var Message: TMessage);
begin
 CaptureBackground;
end;

procedure TTransparentPanel.WMParentNotify(var Message: TWMParentNotify);
begin
  CaptureBackground;
end;

procedure TTransparentPanel.ClearBackground;
begin
  FreeAndNil(FBackground);
end;

procedure TTransparentPanel.ColorBlend(const ACanvas: TCanvas; const ARect: TRect;
  const ABlendColor: TColor; const ABlendValue: Byte);
var
  BMP: TBitmap;
begin
  BMP := TBitmap.Create;
  try
    BMP.Canvas.Brush.Color := ABlendColor;
    BMP.Width := ARect.Right - ARect.Left;
    BMP.Height := ARect.Bottom - ARect.Top;
    BMP.Canvas.FillRect(Rect(0,0,BMP.Width, BMP.Height));

    ACanvas.Draw(ARect.Left, ARect.Top, BMP, ABlendValue);
  finally
    FreeAndNil(BMP);
  end;
end;

procedure TTransparentPanel.SetBlendAlpha(const Value: Byte);
begin
  FBlendAlpha := Value;

  Paint;
end;

procedure TTransparentPanel.SetBlendColor(const Value: TColor);
begin
  FBlendColor := Value;

  Paint;
end;

{ TSemiModalForm }

constructor TSemiModalForm.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited;

  FBlendColor := clWhite;
  FBlendAlpha := 150;

  FTransparentPanel := TTransparentPanel.Create(Self);
end;

procedure TSemiModalForm.SetFormParent(const Value: TWinControl);
begin
  FFormParent := Value;
end;

procedure TSemiModalForm.ShowSemiModalForm(AForm: TForm;
  SemiModalResultHandler: ISemiModalResultHandler);
begin
  if FForm = nil then
  begin
    FForm := AForm;
    FSemiModalResultHandler := SemiModalResultHandler;

    FTransparentPanel.Align := alClient;
    FTransparentPanel.BringToFront;
    FTransparentPanel.Parent := FFormParent;
    FTransparentPanel.BlendColor := FBlendColor;
    FTransparentPanel.BlendAlpha := FBlendAlpha;

    FTransparentPanel.OnResize := OnTransparentPanelResize;

    AForm.Parent := FTransparentPanel;
    FOldFormOnClose := AForm.OnClose;
    AForm.OnClose := OnFormClose;

    RepositionForm;

    AForm.Show;

    FTransparentPanel.ClearBackground;
    FTransparentPanel.Visible := TRUE;
  end;
end;

procedure TSemiModalForm.OnFormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
begin
  FForm.OnClose := FOldFormOnClose;

  try
    FForm.Visible := FALSE;

    FSemiModalResultHandler.SemiModalFormClosed(FForm);
  finally
    FForm.Parent := nil;
    FForm := nil;

    FTransparentPanel.Visible := FALSE;
  end;
end;

procedure TSemiModalForm.Notification(AComponent: TComponent;
  Operation: TOperation);
begin
  inherited Notification(AComponent, Operation);

  if (Operation = opRemove) then
  begin
    if AComponent = FFormParent then
      SetFormParent(nil);
  end;
end;

procedure TSemiModalForm.OnTransparentPanelResize(Sender: TObject);
begin
  RepositionForm;
end;

procedure TSemiModalForm.RepositionForm;
begin
  FForm.Left := (FTransparentPanel.Width div 2) - (FForm.Width div 2);
  FForm.Top := (FTransparentPanel.Height div 2) - (FForm.Height div 2);
end;

end.
```

Can anybody help me with the problems or point me to an alpha blend panel that already exists?

Comment: it is probably only possible over transparent form, due to Windows limitation. Other implementations are "hack-arounds" and cannot be good.

Comment: in this case i'd try to really show on top borderless captionless half-transparent window and show modal non-transparent window over it.

Comment: @Arioch, wouldn't be better to use borderless captionless alpha blended form parented by a base form ? Just asking, I don't know, I get to Delphi in few hours...

Comment: @TLama i don't know too. In GDI transparent style (WS_EX_LAYERED AFAIR) is mutually exclusive with CHILD style. Buttons and such are childs and cannot be transparent other ways than part of transparent windows. Will your TForm having another TForm for parent be considered child or not  - i dunno. But remember he wants it modal - `Form.Parent := another-form` is a recipe to freeze your app on `form.showmodal`

Comment: I haven't said anything about modality... Why would I show the form modally when would be parented anyway ?

Comment: @TLama - see - the answer is following the idea, including modality :-)

Comment: @Arioch Yes, and it's impossible for me to prove I had it first, so thanks, I guess... ;)

Comment: @ngln but u can probably improve it - add optional color, or wallpaper. Make it able to cover not the whole form but some TWinControl over it...  Guess it asks for kind of Fluent Interface. `SemiModal.Over(Form1.Panel1).Color(clWhite).Opacity(50).Show(MyDialog)`

Comment: See also: [How do I put a semi transparent layer on my form](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11867215/how-do-i-put-a-semi-transparent-layer-on-my-form)?

Comment: @Arioch'The: It is correct that in Win2k-Win7, the `WS_EX_LAYERED` style cannot be applied to windows with the `WS_CHILD` style. That capability has finally been added in Win8.

Comment: @Arioch'The, I've seen it, the upvote there is mine...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Thanks for all your suggestions. I've taken the input and created a new component that does exactly what I need. Here's what it looks like:

[image]

The comment that pointed me in the right direction was the one by **NGLN** that I upvoted. If you post it as the answer I'll accept it.

I tried to add the component code to this answer, but StackOverflow wouldn't format it correctly. However, you can download the source and a full demo application [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20130218024334/http://download.easy-ip.net/delphi/SemiModalFormDemo.zip).

The component provides the following functionality:

- The semi modal form is a child of the main form. This means that it
  can be tabbed to just like the other controls.
- The overlay area is drawn correctly with no artefacts.
- The controls under the overlay area are automatically disabled.
- The semi modal form/overlay can be shown/hidden if required e.g.
  switching tabs.
- A SemiModalResult is passed back in an event.

There are still a number of small issues that I would like to iron out. If anybody knows how to fix them, please let me know.

- When the parent form is moved or resized it needs to call the
  ParentFormMoved procedure. This allows the component to
  resize/reposition the overlay form. Is there any way to hook into
  the parent form and detect when it is moved?
- If you mimimise the main form, then restore it, the overlay form appears immediately, then the main form is animated back to it's previous position. Is there a way to detect when the main form has finished animating?
- The rounded corners of the semi modal window are not too pretty. I'm
  not sure there's much that can be done about this as it's down to the
  rectangular region.

Comment: Well, my comment is nothing more than a comment, so I can/may not post it as an answer. If it resulted in an answer, then accept it, whether it is one yourselves or not.

Answer (score 3):

Your code does not show the form modally, and I wonder why you would not. But then, maybe I do not understand the term *semi modal*.

In any case, I think [the idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12842206/how-do-i-create-an-alpha-blended-panel#comment17376567_12842206) to create a half-transparent form on which to show the actual dialog will do just fine:

```
function ShowObviousModal(AForm: TForm; AParent: TWinControl = nil): Integer;
var
  Layer: TForm;
begin
  if AParent = nil then
    AParent := Application.MainForm;
  Layer := TForm.Create(nil);
  try
    Layer.AlphaBlend := True;
    Layer.AlphaBlendValue := 128;
    Layer.BorderStyle := bsNone;
    Layer.Color := clWhite;
    with AParent, ClientOrigin do
      SetWindowPos(Layer.Handle, HWND_TOP, X, Y, ClientWidth, ClientHeight,
        SWP_SHOWWINDOW);
    Result := AForm.ShowModal;
  finally
    Layer.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Usage:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FDialog := TForm2.Create(Self);
  try
    if ShowObviousModal(FDialog) = mrOk then
      Caption := 'OK';
  finally
    FDialog.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Semi-modal usually means that clicking outside the modal window would dismiss it. Is it possible with such approach ?

Comment: @Arioch Yeah, the _semi_-part of this naming comes from OP and I renamed the routine. Further, I think that clicking outside [is another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9856956/delphi-how-do-you-generate-an-event-when-a-user-clicks-outside-modal-dialog).

Comment: Well, you may cover the dialog with one more window, 100% transparent, full-screen, with a region cut away, to make that dialog  act :-D

Comment: No, no ! that was sarcasm! That would kind of kill concept of modality. Well - you can simulate modality by using Windows transparent style and alowing clicks to fall through, etc. But that is a can of worms. I look at David's answer there and i think that the only real option would be to subclass TApplication and check if there is modal window and if there are mouse messages to other windows.

Comment: I don't want to use ShowModal at all as this will stop the rest of the application responding. I need users to be able to switch tabs even if the form is shown. The 'semi modal' form should only be visible on the tab that it is relevant to.