# Runtime TPrintdialog positioning

Tags: delphi, dialog, position

Is the way to change position of TPrintDialog during its showing? I need to center it inside the selected Form. There is no problem with other dialogs like SaveDialog.

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9642293/757830).